# Start redis in the foreground and a node server with one command in parallel but in series

Tags: node.js, unix, npm, redis, command-line-interface

There are tools like [npm-run-all](https://github.com/mysticatea/npm-run-all) that allow persistent processes to run in parallel in one process. I am interested in doing this with `redis` and a `node` server.

However I am looking for a way to run the two in parallel, but only run the `node` process when the `redis` process is verifiably successful.

Is there any unix / bash tool that can achieve what I want?

I can see this working in two ways:

**Option 1**

A tool that ***checks for specific stdout from a process*** for instance `redis` will write `Ready to accept connections` to stdout, the tool would watch for this as a regular expression. When it has received it an event internally would fire and the `node` server would be run.

**Option 2**

A tool that ***checks if / when the http connection is available*** for a specific server and when it receives a proper health check response the internal event is fired and the subsequent `node` server would be run. There would also need to be a timeout involved. The con with this is that it's only specific to processes that spin up servers and endpoints on a consistent local port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a script that responds `PING` command?

```
!/bin/bash

X="`redis-cli ping`"
echo ${X}

while  [ "${X}" != "PONG" ]; do
        echo "redis not yet ready"
        echo "${X}"
        sleep 50
        X="`redis-cli ping`"
done

echo 'Lets start node'
```